# Reading UTF-8 XML and writing it to a file with Python

Tags: python, xml, utf-8

I'm trying to parse UTF-8 XML file and save some parts of it to another file. Problem is, that this is my first Python script ever and I'm totally confused about the character encoding problems I'm finding.

My script fails immediately when it tries to write non-ascii character to a file, but it can print it to command prompt (at least in some level)

Here's the XML (from the parts that matter at least, it's a *.resx file which contains UI strings)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
     <resheader name="foo">
          <value>bar</value>
     </resheader>
     <data name="lorem" xml:space="preserve">
          <value>ipsum öä</value>
     </data>
</root>
```

And here's my python script

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

names = []
values = []

def getStrings(path):
    dom = parse(path)
    data = dom.getElementsByTagName("data")

    for i in range(len(data)):
        name = data[i].getAttribute("name")
        names.append(name)
        value = data[i].getElementsByTagName("value")
        values.append(value[0].firstChild.nodeValue.encode("utf-8"))

def writeToFile():
    with open("uiStrings-fi.py", "w") as f:
        for i in range(len(names)):
            line = names[i] + '="'+ values[i] + '"' #varName='varValue'
            f.write(line)
            f.write("\n")

getStrings("ResourceFile.fi-FI.resx")
writeToFile()
```

And here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "GenerateLanguageFiles.py", line 24, in 
    writeToFile()
  File "GenerateLanguageFiles.py", line 19, in writeToFile
    line = names[i] + '="'+ values[i] + '"' #varName='varValue'
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 2: ordinal not in ran
ge(128)
```

How should I fix my script so it would read and write UTF-8 characters properly? The files I'm trying to generate would be used in test automation with Robots Framework.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to remove the call to `encode()` - that is, replace `nodeValue.encode("utf-8")` with `nodeValue` - and then change the call to `open()` to

```
with open("uiStrings-fi.py", "w", "utf-8") as f:
```

This uses a "Unicode-aware" version of `open()` which you will need to import from the `codecs` module, so also add

```
from codecs import open
```

to the top of the file.

The issue is that when you were calling `nodeValue.encode("utf-8")`, you were converting a Unicode string (Python's internal representation that can store all Unicode characters) into a regular string (which can only store single-byte characters 0-255). Later on, when you construct the line to write to the output file, `names[i]` is still a Unicode string but `values[i]` is a regular string. Python tries to convert the regular string to Unicode, which is the more general type, but because you don't specify an explicit conversion, it uses the ASCII codec, which is the default, and ASCII can't handle characters with byte values greater than 127. Unfortunately, several of those do occur in the string `values[i]` because the UTF-8 encoding uses those upper-range bytes frequently. So Python complains that it sees a character it can't handle. The solution, as I said above, is to defer the conversion from Unicode to bytes until the last possible moment, and you do that by using the Unicode-aware version of open (which will handle the encoding for you).

Now that I think about it, instead of what I said above, an alternate solution would be to replace `names[i]` with `names[i].encode("utf-8")`. That way, you convert `names[i]` into a regular string as well, and Python has no reason to try to convert `values[i]` back to Unicode. Although, one could make the argument that it's good practice to keep your strings as Unicode objects until you write them out to the file... if nothing else, I believe `unicode` becomes the default in Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

The XML parser decodes the UTF-8 encoding of the input when it reads the file and all the text nodes and attributes of the resulting DOM are then unicode objects. When you select the interesting data from the DOM, you re-encode the `values` as UTF-8, but you don't encode the `names`. The resulting `values` array contains encoded byte strings while the `names` array still contains unicode objects.

In the line where the encoding error is thrown, Python tries to concatenate such a unicode name and a byte string value. To do so, both values have to be of the same type and Python tries to convert the byte string `values[i]` to unicode, but it doesn't know that it's UTF-8 encoded and fails when it tries to use the ASCII codec.

The easiest way to work around this would be to keep all the strings as Unicode objects and just encode them to UTF-8 when they are written to the file:

```
values.append(value[0].firstChild.nodeValue) # encode not yet
...
f.write(line.encode('utf-8')) # but now
```